# React Dom append child onClick is not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render a child component dynamically.

```
const widgetRef = React.useRef([]);
const saveWidgetRef = (index) => (element) => {
    console.log('widget:'+index);
    widgetRef.current[index] = element;
  }
const handleFocus = (e,index) => {

    
    if(widgetRef.current[index]){
          e.target.focus();
        
    }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<div builder-element="BlockElement" builder-draggable=""  ref={saveWidgetRef(widgetItemsCount)} 
onHover={(e) => {hoverSetWidgetIndex(e,widgetItemsCount)}}  class="px-3 my-3" onMouseEnter={toggleHover}
      onMouseLeave={toggleHover} >
 <TextWidget widget_index={widgetItemsCount} callClickFunction={handleFocus} /></div>,
containerRef.current[currentIndex]);
```

TextWidget

```
import React from "react";
import "./TextWidget.css";

function TextWidget(props) {

  console.log(props);
  return (

    <p builder-element="" builder-inline-edit="" onClick={(e)=>{props.callClickFunction(e,props.widget_index)}} onFocus={(e) => {
        console.log('Focused on input');
      }} class="builder-class-element-selected mce-content-body" id="mce_0" contentEditable={true}  spellCheck={false}>I'm a new Text block ready for your content.</p>
    
  );
}

export default TextWidget;
```

when I click the child TextWidget paragraph it needs to be focused.

But click event is not called.

```
.drag_container:after {
  content: "Drag block(s) here!";
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.drag_container:before {
  content: "blur_on";
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Material Icons Outlined";
  margin-top: -25px;
}
```

I found the issue but need an solution
when I apply to the container before and after
click and drag is not working

Please find the codesandbox
[enter link description here](https://29zln.csb.app/src/App.js:)

Comment: what are `widgetRef` and `saveWidgetRef`? an useful piece of cose is not shown

Comment: Is the click event not called or the focus event not called? Or both? I think the click event should at least be called.

Comment: click event is not called. I have updated the questions and added functions

Comment: If you add  tabIndex="1" to `p` atleast focus will be called. As I mentioned click should be called in anycase, don't know why it is not. Can you provide a codesandbox with minimal example?

Comment: I am rendering after drag and drop

Comment: I have this issue when I use with before and after css

Comment: I was able to recreate the issue i sandbax